# Newton Raphson method JS+html

Tags: javascript, html

Need help, because I have an error in my code and I can't see it.

I'm trying to do a newton raphson method.

The user enters a polinomy and the function calculates the derivate, then applys the Newton's raphson formula and shows the final result in a table.

My problem is that I can't make it work, because I can't show the final table with the results.

See an example here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Qyddoy?editors=101

Thats my JS code.

```
function funcion(func, x) {
    var nuevaFuncion= func.replace(/x/g, x);
    return eval(nuevaFuncion);
}


function derivada(x) {
    var func = document.getElementsByName("func")[0].value.trim();
    var derivative = nerdamer('diff(' + func + ')').evaluate();
}

function procesar(formulario) {
    var i = 0;
    var func = document.getElementsByName("func")[0].value;
    var err, x_1, x = parseFloat(formulario.x.value);
    var resultado = '<table border="3"><tr><td align="center">i</td><td align="center">x<sub></sub></td><td align="center">error</td></tr>';
    do {
        x_1 = x;
        x = x - funcion(func, x) / derivada(x);
        err = Math.abs((x - x_1) / x);
        resultado += '<tr><td>x<sub>' + i + '</sub></td><td>' + x_1 + '</td><td>' + err + '</td></tr>';
        i++;
    } while (x != x_1 && i < 100);
    document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML = resultado + '</tbody>    </table><br>' + (i == 100 ? 'La solucion no es convergente. ' : 'La solucion es ' + x);
return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things that I would do differently. The first is that I would avoid replacing and using eval and let nerdamer do the work. For example sin(x) would give an error since there isn't a native JS function called sin but rather Math.sin. I'm guessing your `i < 100` is a safety. I prefer using a break statement since this is a lot easier to read and debug in my opinion. Also if you already know the variable name you can avoid calling buildFunction and use evaluate instead for example if the variable is x

`nerdamer(func).evaluate({x:x});`

And lastly, Newton's method requires some stop condition up to some accuracy. Your stop condition of `x != x_1` is risky at best.

Here are my edits
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gPgXbK?editors=101

```
function funcion(func, x) {
    return nerdamer(func).buildFunction().call(undefined, x);
}


function derivada(x){
  var func = document.getElementsByName("func")[0].value.trim();
  return nerdamer('diff(' + func + ')').buildFunction().call(undefined, x);
}



function procesar(formulario) {
    var i = 0;
    var func = document.getElementsByName("func")[0].value;

    var err, x_1, x = parseFloat(formulario.x.value);
    var resultado = '<table border="3"><tr><td align="center">i</td><td align="center">x<sub></sub></td><td align="center">error</td></tr>';
    do {
        var x_1 = x - funcion(func, x) / derivada(x);
        //get the error
        var e = Math.abs(x-x_1);
        x = x_1
        err = Math.abs((x - x_1) / x);
        resultado += '<tr><td>x<sub>' + i + '</sub></td><td>' + x_1 + '</td><td>' + err + '</td></tr>';
        i++;
        //I imagine that this is your safety so I would implement it like this
        if(i > 100) break;
    } while (e > 0.01);
document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML = resultado + '</tbody></table><br>' + (i == 100 ? 'La solucion no es convergente. ' : 'La solucion es ' + x);
return false;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

The function `derivada` doesn't return nothing so the division in `procesar` function fails.

You have to return a value so the calculus can go ahead. And I think you want to return the result of derivating the function, like this:

```
function derivada(x) {
    var func = document.getElementsByName("func")[0].value.trim();
    var derivative = nerdamer('diff(' + func + ')').evaluate();
    return eval(derivative.text());
}
```